# pine script how to save multiple data of particular bar for compare in future?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I want to save high, low, open, close and one another value of a particular bar when a condition happened.

and next I want to compare that with current bar and calculate the distance to that point.

how can I save 5 float value in 2D array or something like that?

and how can I get the distance ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
var arrayname = array.new_float(0)
if condition 
    array.push(arrayname, high)
if barstate.islast 
    for i = 0 to array.size(arrayname) - 1
        compare block
```

you can declare other arrays for open, close, and low
and compare them with the last candle data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).